# Scala break point in IntelliJ not working

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I'm using IntelliJ 16.1.2 and Scala 2.12.1.
When I set a break point in the following code, it doesn't work:

```
object Test extends App{

  val array = Array(1,5,6,23,66,45,232)

  array.foreach(e =>
    println(e) //breakpoint 1
  )
  println("test") //breakpoint 2
}
```

The console output is:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63758', transport: 'socket'
1
5
6
23
66
45
232
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63758', transport: 'socket'
test

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So the code gets executed correctly and the process stops on the second break point, but not on the first one and I don't understand why. (I have this problem in all my projects. I've tried creating a new project from scratch and simply added the code from above but it doesn't help)

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?
Thanks for your support!

Comment: 1. Is the formatting the same?

2. Right click on breakpoint and check if 'Suspend' and 'Enabled' are checked.

Comment: yes breakpoints are the same (enabled and suspend checked, no condition etc.)
what do you mean by formatting?

Comment: If you would have `array.foreach(e => println(e))` instead of `array.foreach(e => \n println(e) \n)` then it could break only once.

Comment: Do you mean that `1
5
6
23
66
45
232` get executed without breaks?

Comment: @Rumid yes the formatting is the same as above and the break point was set on the line indicated

Comment: @RameshMaharjan exactly. once the program gets paused at the break point 2, the numbers have already been printed and break point 1 was never activated

Comment: @simon May be step by step process would help us track where you are doing wrong. I did the same as in your question and it was working fine

Comment: it turns out, i was using scala 2.12 but my scala plugin in intellij was not up to date and thus the problem occured